# What causes EVariantBadVarTypeError exception?

Tags: delphi, exception, variant

I have an exception of type EVariantBadVarTypeError on application closure.

[image]

I want to debug my application by myself but the [Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Variants.EVariantBadVarTypeError) is not so clear to me and I don't exactly know which kind of error I should look for in my code..

> **EVariantBadVarTypeError** is the exception class for variant type
>   errors.
>
> **EVariantBadVarTypeError** is raised when a variant operation
>   fails because of a value that isn't a valid variant type.

Could someone tell me a clearer explanation and an example which causes this kind of exception? In particular, I don't know which values are not "valid variant types".

Comment: Have you not looked at Variants.Pas?  This shows where it is raised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, `Variant` and `OleVariant` internally use [COM Automation functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221236.aspx) for various `VARIANT` operations. `EVariantBadVarTypeError` is raised when one of the `VARIANT` functions (like [`VariantCopy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221697.aspx), [`VariantClear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221165.aspx), [`VariantChangeTypeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221634.aspx), [`VarI4FromStr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221194.aspx), etc) fails with a [`VAR_BADVARTYPE`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/VarUtils_VAR_BADVARTYPE.html) error:

> The variant type of the input parameter is not valid.

Which implies that the variant's `vt` field specifies a data type that is not compatible with the operation that is being performed.

That explains *what* the exception is, but not *why* it is being raised in your app.  Without more details about what your code is doing when the exception is raised, what the stack trace looks like leading up to the exception being raised, etc, there is no way for anyone here to diagnose what is actually happening or how to fix it.  You will have to debug your code to figure it out.

Comment: I premise that I want to debug my application by myself, I just need to know a little bit more about the error in order to be able to understand what to look for. Could you please add an example or a link that explains which kind of operations aren't allowed for each variant types?

Answer (score 1):

Valid Variant types string, int, real, etc. Anything else, like an object, is not a valid variant. More info here:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Variant_Types

Comment: If i try to assign an object to a Variant variable, I've got an error on compiling. Could you please add an example which causes the exception?